# Flutter Fitness App - Any way to integrate health in flutter app

Tags: healthkit, heartrate, google-healthcare-api, google-health, flutter-health

I'm working on on fitness/health app using flutter framework. I'm using google health for android and apple health for apple. The data is good for steps but not showing heart rate. Is there any proper way to integrate google health and apple health into any flutter app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below package for health data. This lib supports both android and iOS.
https://pub.dev/packages/health

Note: This lib doesn't support background fetch so you have to write native code or use another library.